# remove current profile from Windows 7 explorer.exe?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, administrator

Thanks very much for the discussion about removing unwanted folder-views from Windows 7 `explorer.exe` via reg edits. I've cleaned up my Nav pane quite a bit and am much happier.

There is one remaining entry I would like to know if it's possible to get rid of: I am currently logged into Windows 7 as Administrator. At the top of the Navigation pane (I.e. the first entry), immediately under Desktop, is "Administrator." I assume it's the profile directory showing me which login is active. Is there any way to hide that entry?

Comment: A screenshot would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the Favorites section of the nav pane? In that case, just right click on the link and click Remove.

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If not, let me know and I can try to help with the issue.